# Data manupulation python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get the mode of models at column level and the find the error associated with that model
if two or more more modes are received then we select the model with least error out of these two modes

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Iteration1': ["M2",'M1',"M3","M5","M4","M6"],
        'Iteration1_error': [96,98,34,19,22,9],
        'Iteration2': ["M3",'M1',"M1","M5","M6","M4"],
        'Iteration2_error': [76,88,54,12,92,19],
        'Iteration3': ["M3",'M1',"M1","M5","M6","M4"],
        'Iteration3_error': [66,68,84,52,72,89]}

Input1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, 
                     columns=['Iteration1','Iteration1_error','Iteration2','Iteration2_error','Iteration3','Iteration3_error'], 
                     index=['I1', 'I2','I3','I4','I5','I6'])

print(Input1)

data2 = {'Iteration1': ["M2",'M1',"M3","M5","M4","M6"],
        'Iteration1_error': [96,98,34,19,22,9],
        'Iteration2': ["M3",'M1',"M1","M5","M6","M4"],
        'Iteration2_error': [76,88,54,12,92,19],
        'Iteration3': ["M3",'M1',"M1","M5","M6","M4"],
        'Iteration3_error': [66,68,84,52,72,89],
        'Mode of model name in all iterations':['M3','M1','M1','M5','M6','M4'],
        'Best model error':[66,68,54,12,72,19]
       }

Output1 = pd.DataFrame(data2, 
                     columns=['Iteration1','Iteration1_error','Iteration2','Iteration2_error','Iteration3','Iteration3_error','Mode of model name in all iterations','Best model error'], 
                     index=['I1', 'I2','I3','I4','I5','I6'])


print(Output1)
```

Question: So we are expecting an output with two etc columns at the end , one tells us about mode at column level second tells about the error of that mode, first 6 columns are input dataframe,  incase two modes or more  are received example ("M1","M2","M3") all three values are different so technically it will have 3 modes so model with least accuracy will be selected

What I tried: I was able to get the mode at column level by using .mode(numeric_only=False) but what issue I am getting how can I get that modes error from 2nd, 4th and 6th column, there I am stuck at

Comment: Hi. What's exactly the question?

Comment: how to generate last two columns  "Mode of model name in all iterations" and  'Best model error' from the first 6 columns,, the logic I have already stated above..

Comment: please add your attempt to the question as well, so is not a free code service. Also, do check out how to provide a [mre] so that others can help.

Comment: Guys did some changes in the question, hope so that helps,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#filter only columns by Iteration with number
df = Input1.filter(regex='Iteration\d+$')
#get first mode
s = df.mode(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
#compare df for all possible modes, add suffix for match errors columns, 
#last filter original with min
s1 = Input1.where(df.eq(s, axis=0).add_suffix('_error')).min(axis=1)

#add new columns
Output1 = Input1.assign(best_mode = s, best_error=s1)
print (Output1)
   Iteration1  Iteration1_error Iteration2  Iteration2_error Iteration3  \
I1         M2                96         M3                76         M3   
I2         M1                98         M1                88         M1   
I3         M3                34         M1                54         M1   
I4         M5                19         M5                12         M5   
I5         M4                22         M6                92         M6   
I6         M6                 9         M4                19         M4   

    Iteration3_error best_mode  best_error  
I1                66        M3        66.0  
I2                68        M1        68.0  
I3                84        M1        54.0  
I4                52        M5        12.0  
I5                72        M6        72.0  
I6                89        M4        19.0
```

Another idea if is possible use pair and unpairs columns (in data has to exist all pairs ech other, sorted):

```
df = Input1.iloc[:, ::2]
s = df.mode(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
s1 = Input1.iloc[:, 1::2].where(df.eq(s, axis=0).to_numpy()).min(axis=1)

Output1 = Input1.assign(best_mode = s, best_error=s1)
```